# How to write the first move of a PGN that starts with blacks?

Tags: pgn

Some programs/websites use `1. ... e5 2.f3` (e.g [Arena](http://www.playwitharena.com/) or [LT-PGN-Viewer](http://www.lutanho.net/pgn/pgnviewer.html)) while others use `1...e5 2.f3` (e.g [chess.com](http://chess.com)). To achieve this, I loaded a FEN that is black-to-move, then made a move.

Which one is best to use? What does the specs say about this?

---

Just to make this clear, my question is *not* about using 3 dots after a white move comment, for this one I got to the conclusion that it is best to use `1.e4 { comment } 1...e5 2.Nf3` over `1.e4 { comment } e5 2.Nf3`, but it is somewhat optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1...e5` is best. I quote from Section 8.2.2.2 of [the PGN specification](http://www6.chessclub.com/help/PGN-spec), with the relevant phrases in bold:

> There are two export format move number indication formats, one for use appearing immediately before a white move element and one for use
>   appearing immediately before a black move element.  A white move
>   number indication is formed from the integer giving the fullmove
>   number with a single period character appended.  **A black move number
>   indication is formed from the integer giving the fullmove number with
>   three period characters appended.**
>
> All white move elements have a preceding move number indication.  A
>   black move element has a preceding move number indication only in two
>   cases: first, if there is intervening annotation or commentary between
>   the black move and the previous white move; and second, **if there is no
>   previous white move in the special case where a game starts from a
>   position where Black is the active player.**